# Can not connect Postgres after sometimes

Tags: configuration, database-connection, postgresql-13, postgresql.conf

Its been a week that I can not connect to Postgres 13 server after some period of idle time (I do not connect to database for about 1 - 2 hours), although it's status is Active. I am the only one accessing this database right now using PGADMIN.

Anyway, after restarting, the operation goes back to normal. What seems to be the problem ?What should I do ?

My postgres database runs on a AWS with spec:

```
DB Type: OLTP
RAM: 8
CPU: 2
Connection: 100
```

Any suggestions welcome.
thanks